# Superfish dropdown menus stay open after hovering on then off of them in Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, css, drupal-7, superfish

I have a Superfish Horizontal menu (drupal 7). When I hover over a menu item with a subpage the dropdown menus appear but DO NOT disappear when I hover over other menu items (see below). They all just stay open.

I dealt with this before with inherited code and I cannot remember how to fix. I believe it was a CSS fix? Any help would be greatly appreciated. thx.

Screenshot: [Screenshot of open dropdowns](http://pennlps.org/img/superfish-screen-01.png)